# xslt replace array tag name with template match

Tags: json, xslt, wso2, xslt-2.0, transformation

I have a jsonPayload like:

```
{
  "test": {
    "demo": [
      {
        "thirdA": {
          "forthB": [
            {
              "aaa": [
                {
                  "bbb": "bbb"
                }
              ],
              "ccc": "ccc",
              "ddd": "ddd",
              "eee": "eee",
              "fff": "fff",
              "ggg": "ggg"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "thirdA": {
          "forthB": [
            {
              "aaa": [
                {
                  "bbb": "bbb1"
                }
              ],
              "ccc": "ccc1",
              "ddd": "ddd2",
              "eee": "eee3",
              "fff": "fff4",
              "ggg": "ggg5"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to replace the `thirdA` with `third` and `forthB` with `forth` with using xslt. I tried this but `forthB` jsonArray which has one jsonElement was returned jsonObject. When I added a second jsonObject in first `forthB`, I got jsonArray in first `demo` jsonObject, but other forthB inside of second `demo` jsonArray was still jsonObject.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
                <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>     
                <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
                   <xsl:copy>                              
                          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                   </xsl:copy>
                </xsl:template>
                <xsl:template match="//jsonObject/test/demo/thirdA[local-name()='thirdA']">
                    <third>
                        <xsl:apply-templates />
                    </third>
                </xsl:template>
                <xsl:template match="processing-instruction('xml-multiple')[.='forthB']"/>
                <xsl:template match="//jsonObject/test/demo/thirdA/forthB[local-name()='forthB']">
                    <xsl:if test="count(//jsonObject/test/demo/thirdA/forthB) >0">
                      <xsl:processing-instruction name="xml-multiple"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <third>
                        <xsl:apply-templates />
                    </third>
                </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks for any idea!

Regards

Comment: Do you have access to the actual XML used as input to this transformation? It will be very difficult to answer your question properly without knowing more about how this JSON-to-XML conversion behaves.

Comment: agree with @TrevorLawrence.. also if you provide your mediation flow configuration we can get better idea.. or put a log mediator before and after your transformation provide us the output